# What are some of the most effective ways for 3D reconstruction?

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, photogrammetry

As I've been doing some research into 3D reconstruction (modeling of physical 3D objects), I've encountered many solutions. I'm curious what are some effective ways for reconstructing 3D objects. For example:

- Stereoscopic 3D reconstruction with OpenCV
- Photogrammetry from a collection of images
- LIDAR sensors
- ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the accuracy you want to achieve and the information you need. If you're okay with few cm accuracy and no real rgb data go for the lidar.

Photogrammetry from a collection of images is usually on the scale of ppm when it comes to accuracy. But to achieve this accuracy you'll have to go through post processing and use special cameras.

OpenCV is the low cost version of photogrammetry. You have fast but not very accurate algorithmy for every-day cameras.

So it's all about money/time you have and the geometric/radiometric accuracy you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm curious why you say that OpenCV is the low cost version of photogrammetry.

Comment: Because it's open-source, has a BSD licence and is very well tested. The chosen algorithms make it superior for certain tasks such as robot vision and all processes where performance and not accuracy is the main goal.